# Proof that $F$ has a global minimun in $y=u$ where $u(x)=\frac{x-x_0}{x_1-x_0}$

Tags: analysis, optimization, calculus-of-variations

Let $x_0,x_1\in \mathbb{R}$ such that  $x_0<x_1$ and $F$ the set of functions $y\in C^{1}([x_0,x_1];\mathbb{R})$ such that $y(x_0)=0$ and $y(x_1)=1$ Let $y\in F$
$$F[y]=\int_{x_0}^{x_1} (y')^2dx$$
Proof that $F$ has a global minimum in $y=u$ where $u(x)=\frac{x-x_0}{x_1-x_0}$

Using the Euler-Langrange equations it is easy to prove that it is a local minimum but I need it to be a global minimum and the Euler-Lagrange equations do not help in this case. How can I prove this?

I need to prove that $F[u]<F[y]$ for all $y \in F$.

Comment: You can try with the second variation

Comment: It is a bit confusing to use $F$ for both the functional and the constraint set.

Comment: Why is no answer accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid confusion I will use $f$ to denote the functional in question.

Note that $f$ is convex and so we have
$f(y)-f(u) \ge d f(u, y-u)$, where $df$ is the Gateaux derivative of $f$ at $u$ in the direction $y-u$.

Hence $u$ is a global $\min$ **iff** $d f(u, y-u) \ge 0$ for all $y \in F$.

It is not difficult to show that $d f(u, y-u) = 2 \int_{x_0}^{x_1} u'(x) (y'(x)-u'(x)) dx$, and substituting the actual value for the first instance of $u'$ we
get $df(u,y-u) = { 1\over x_1-x_0} ((y(1)-u(1))-(y(0)-u(0))$ and if $y \in F$
we get $df(u,y-u) = 0$. Hence $u$ is a global minimiser.

Answer (score 0):

You can argue that Legendre's condition $f_{y'y'}=2>0$ holds strictly, and there are no conjugate points (w.r.t. the Jacobi equation) to $0$ in $[0,1]$. Therefore the second variation is strongly positive definite at every point, your functional is convex and the only extremal is the global minimum

Comment: But I don't understand where you use the fact that $u(x)=\frac{x-x_0}{x_1-x_0}$

Comment: In this particular case, the second variation is a constant quadratic functional, the same at every point. It happens to be positive semidefinite, implying that your functional is convex (indeed, it is quadratic!). Such functional can only have local minima, and all of them are also global. In a more general case, you would have to look at $f_{yy}, f_{yy'}$ and (most importantly) $f_{y'y'}$ along your extremal. No need in this case. It is like having a function of one variable $g(t)=at^2+bt+c$ and you know that $a>0$ and $x_0$ is a local min. Then you know that it is global as well.